# Antd: how to set button hover color?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have the following configuration in the **antd.customize.less** file:

```
@btn-primary-bg: #ffe900;
@btn-primary-color: @primary-color;

@btn-default-color: @primary-color;
@btn-default-bg: #ffffff;
```

On hovering a primary button everything is ok, but on hovering a default button the text color in the button changes to @btn-primary-bg, which I want to override, but I couldn't find any property like "@btn-default-hover-color" [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less). How can this be overridden, if at all?

Comment: I tried to add this:
.ant-btn:hover {
  color: @primary-color;
}
but it didn't help

Comment: But why do you want to override the hover text color for the default button? What is your use case?

Comment: There is no way to override the hover color of the default button? Check [here]. And your comment solution is the only way to go. You may be facing the [cascade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade) or specificity issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue but I'm still looking for a better solution. However, for the moment, I can suggest that you add something like this to your global style file:

```
.ant-btn-default:hover, .ant-btn-default:focus {
  border-color: #bee2e5;
  color: #fff;
}
```

**UPDATE**

After antd has been updated to version 5.0.0 there is a prettier way to do it using [ConfigProvider](https://ant.design/components/config-provider).

Let's suppose we have wrapped our App and assigned to the theme an object with parameters.

```
<ConfigProvider theme={{
  components: {
    Button: {
       colorPrimaryBorderHover: 'red',
       colorPrimaryHover: 'lightgray',
       colorPrimary: 'red',
       colorPrimaryActive: 'lightgray',
       colorPrimaryTextHover: 'lightgray',
    }
  }
}}>
  <App />
</ConfigProvider>
```

Acctually there are a lot of parameters to customize the  appereance of your app which you can find in your
`node_modules/antd/es/config-provider/context.d.ts` file

However your config might be huge but to keep your code readable you might pass this object with interface of *ThemeConfig* as an exported value from another .ts file.

```
<ConfigProvider theme={myCustomTheme}>
  ...
```

Comment: still no better way in v4?

Comment: there is a npm module called [craco](https://github.com/dilanx/craco) which help you with overrides. By the way take a look on antd page with [related documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#advanced-guides)

Comment: we ejected our app and using webpack, is it still appliable? note: v4 user here

Answer (score 2):

Working with reassigning [less variables](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less). Thied to edit everything that connected with @primary-color, nothing changed color generated by Antd for hover/active state. Looks like there is no way to do this with less variables.