# How can I change the text color of an Ant Design button component when it is disabled?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I've been trying using styled-components -

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
    .and-btn-primary[disabled] {
       background-color: red;
       color: red;
    }
`;
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using -

```
:disabled {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

to override antd

Answer (score 3):

Please check out this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70700539/antd-how-to-set-button-hover-color/73720148#73720148)
In your case you can override your css like this:

```
.ant-btn-default:disabled{
     background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tired it but it didn't work (even with !important), but I ended up using - 
':disabled {
    background-color: blue !important;
  }'
and it worked

Comment: Probably it didn't work for you because you used primary button, but I made an example for default.  try `.and-btn-primary:disabled{background-color: red;}` it should work without _!important_ keyword. 
P.S. By the way click F12 in your browser -> then Ctrl+Shift+C -> then click on the element on your page which css you are looking for it's useful :)

Comment: thanks for the cool keyboard shortcut! 
I know how to use inspect and search for a specific element but I always love to add cool new shortcuts in my life!
and I've tried your suggestion but it turns the button white for some reason, and there's no mention of the red color, thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 1):

`

```
<ConfigProvider
    theme={{
        token: {
            colorPrimary: '#00aaa7',
            colorTextDisabled:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)'
        }            
    }}
>

</ConfigProvider>
```

`